# Double-click event fires at window level and control level, even when it is handled within the control

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am working on a WPF application where I have a Window level double-click event that maximizes the app window when a user double-clicks anywhere within the window. However, I also have a custom control within the app window, and a separate double-click event within the custom control. When a user double-clicks in the custom control, only the control's double-click event should fire, and the window should not resize. My code looks something like this:

```
public class Window 
{
    private void window_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        /// Maximize/minimize window
    }

    private void myCustomControl_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        /// Do other things, but PLEASE don't resize!
        e.Handled = true;
    } 
}
```

And my XAML looks something like this:

```
<Window x:class="MyProject.MyWindow"
     MouseDoubleClick="window_DoubleClick">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0">
        <local:myCustomControl
            MouseDoubleClick="myCustomControl_DoubleClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Unfortunately, with this code in place, when the user double-clicks in the control, the control event fires, but the Window event fires as well. I have tried setting e.Handled=true in the control event, but the Window event fires anyway. The only thing that has stopped the Window level double-click event from firing is handling the custom control's preview double-click event using this:

```
private void myCustomControl_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Though the preview event stops the Window double-click before it can fire, I can't use it without having to refactor a good bit of code. My custom control has a few child controls that also handle its double-click event. If the preview event gets called at the parent control level, the double-click event never tunnels down through the child controls, and thus double-clicking doesn't do what I want it to do. If possible, I would like to avoid having to refactor any of the code in the child controls. That being said, my question is this: Is there any way to stop the Window-level double-click event from firing once the control's double-click event has been handled? I've been driving myself crazy trying to figure this out.. any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that MouseDoubleClick only appears to bubble, but really doesn't. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx):

> Although this routed event seems to follow a bubbling route through an element tree, it actually is a direct routed event that is raised along the element tree by each UIElement. If you set the Handled property to true in a MouseDoubleClick event handler, subsequent MouseDoubleClick events along the route will occur with Handled set to false.

Instead you could use the MouseLeftButtonDown event and check the clickcount:

```
private void myCustomControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        //do something
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Note: This does not work on `MouseLeftButtonUp` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Because all of my custom control's children had events tied to double-click, I opted to change the window-level event handler to MouseLeftButtonDown. It works beautifully now! Thanks again!

Comment: @chelsea You're welcome! The double click event can be a pain to use, so I regularly try to avoid it completely.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any documentation that indicates why this event doesn't bubble like the rest? The MSDN article doesn't really provide an explanation for why it is done this way.

Comment: @chelsea none that I know off

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add a check for your custom control in your window level event.  Do a typeof check  on the sender if it matches your  custom control just return out of it.

Comment: I've actually tried that just to see what would happen. Unfortunately, the type always appears to be the application window, regardless of whether or not the double-click occurred within the control.